# Windows syscall

Tags: winapi, go

So I'm trying to get the File Handle on a socket in windows.

Using like the following:

```
            address, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", "192.168.9.144:8080")                                                                                                                                     
            if err != nil {                                                                                                                                                                                     
                    fmt.Println(err)                                                                                                                                                                            
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, address)                                                                                                                                                       
            fmt.Println("Connected")                                                                                                                                                                            
            // conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, address)                                                                                                                                                    
            if err != nil {                                                                                                                                                                                     
                    fmt.Println("Can't conenct")                                                                                                                                                                
                    log.Fatal(err)                                                                                                                                                                              
     }
     conn.File() 
     conn.Fd()
```

conn.File() Fails and states it's not supported by windows

Next I tried to use the windows api function _get_osfhandle

```
var (
        procGetOSfHandle = msvcrt.NewProc("_get_osfhandle")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
)                                                                                                                                                                                                           

func GetOSfHandle(fd uintptr) (uintptr, error) {                                                                                                                                                            
        value, _, err := procGetOSfHandle.Call(fd)                                                                                                                                                          
        return value, err                                                                                                                                                                                   
} 
hand, _ := GetOSfHandle(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(conn)))
```

hand returns 4294967295 which turns out to be not real as in "xff\xff\xff\xff"

I then tried just to use the windows API for socket and ran into an issue with WSARecv.  This is the following code used:

```
       var d syscall.WSAData                                                                                                                                                                           
       syscall.WSAStartup(uint32(0x202), &d)                                                                                                                                                           
       fd, _ := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_INET, syscall.SOCK_STREAM, 0)                                                                                                                                
       addr := syscall.SockaddrInet4{Port: 8080, Addr: [4]byte{192, 168, 9, 144}}                                                                                                                      
       var buf [4]byte                                                                                                                                                                                 
       syscall.Connect(fd, &addr)                                                                                                                                                                      
       dataBuf := syscall.WSABuf{Len: uint32(4), Buf: &buf[0]}                                                                                                                                         
       o := syscall.Overlapped{}                                                                                                                                                                       
       flags := uint32(0)                                                                                                                                                                              
       qty := uint32(0)                                                                                                                                                                                
       syscall.WSARecv(fd, &dataBuf, 1, &qty, &flags, &o, nil)                                                                                                                                         
       fmt.Println(buf)
```

The code connects but I don't see and data received.  It seems I don't seem to have the WSARecv options correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use _get_osfhandle - error, this is absolute unrelated func here

Comment: You are using `WSARecv` in asynchronous mode, sort of anyway. If you want `WSARecv` to block until data is read, pass `nil` as the *lpOverlapped* parameter.

Comment: @IInspectable you were absolutely right.  I've changed that flag to a nil but for some reason it doesn't grab the entire data stream from the server.  Some times it does some times it doesn't.

Once the four bytes are received, I take that value which is the length of the data (770000 bytes) but it doesn't seem to write all the data from the server to the buffer

Comment: @llnspectable I figured it out.  I had to keep calling WSARecv to get more of the data.

Comment: No, you don't. You just have to pass a larger buffer.